# Which sections of ISS belongs to each space agency part of ISS program and what is the habitable volume for each section?

Tags: iss

Which parts (sections or modules) of International Space Station (ISS) belongs to which space agencies or countries that are part of ISS program? I am interested to know statistical information, about the habitable volume in value for all sections of each space agency. A comparison by habitable volume between sections controlled or developed by each space agency or country.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Can you find info about the habitable volume for each module or section, because i haven't found yet for all of them

Comment: I think it is doable but it will be a big task.

Answer (score 2):

US segment (NASA, ESA, CSA, JAXA) includes:

1. [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Unity)
2. [Harmony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Harmony) 75.5 m^3
3. [Tranquility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Tranquility) and [Cupola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Cupola)
4. [Destiny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Destiny) 106 m^3 **(1)**
5. [Columbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Columbus) Lab (ESA)
6. [Kibo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Kib.C5.8D) Lab (JAXA)
7. [Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Quest) Airlock
8. [Leonardo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Leonardo)
9. Pressurized Mating Adapter

Russian Orbital Segment

1. [Zvezda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Zvezda) 46,7 m^3
2. [Zarya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Zarya) 71.5 m^3 **(1)**
3. [Rassvett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Rassvet) 5.85 m^3
4. [Pirs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Pirs_and_Poisk) 13 m^3
5. [Poisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station#Pirs_and_Poisk) 10.7 m^3

I'll try adding the volumes later, but most of them can be found on Wikipedia.

---

(1) Pressured area, not living area

Comment: Habitable volume is more than half of the question. Yeah some of them are in wikipedia, but for the other segments is difficult to find info even in other websites, to complete let say the habitable volume's mosaic.

Comment: Unless you plan on tracking all the relevant info down yourself, you should consider making this a community wiki. I wouldn't force you to surrender your rep, but I would consider this a good question for folks to collaborate on.

Comment: Community wiki or not, I added a bunch of links.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Community wiki :-)